# Facebook Like Button Problem On Blogger's Magazine Style Template

Tags: facebook, blogs, blogger, xfbml

I'm trying to put the Facebook Like button using XFBML in my Blogger blog. I want it to display a different button for each post, not the same for all the blog.

What's happening is that the like button is displayed, but it's exactly the same one for all the posts. I think its because of my blogger template. I hope you guys can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

My Url: http://www.7zero-fa.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0):

if you can edit the code then its a case of removing the

> href="google.com"

then it will get href based on page from which it was clicked.